# Displaying a document from a database without storing it on the harddrive

Tags: windev

I'm actually on a time performance project.

The goal is to display a document stored in a blog field on a database (mysql) without having to write it on the hard drive.

The whole document must be stored in RAM only, and displayed from there for confidentiality purposes.

I'm having trouble to do that, as the functions allowing to perform the operation takes for parameter the physical path of the file.

I've also searched for alternative solutions, like for example a piece of software allowing to make windows believe that some defined part of the RAM is a removable disk, or something like that. I haven't foud anything that fitted my needs.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm forced to do this application with Windev 12

Comment: sorry, I mean a blob field, not a "blog" one...

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551595/temp-file-that-exists-only-in-ram)

Comment: As I mentionned, the function which displays a document has one mandatory param who is the physical location of the file. This means I'm unable to display anything by now (unless it is stored in the hard drive, obviously). Nonetheless, your link is interesting. But it might only be the next step...

Comment: I would agree if it wasn't a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I found a way to do that, giving a logical path to the functions, which points on a remote virtual drive. Windev displays the files as wanted. Problem solved!